# Android Studio Emulator Not Starting: Could not find GLES 2.x config

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio-2.2

I just installed the latest android studio but the emulator does not start. instead, it pops up this error to me

```
getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
```

Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the option '-gpu off' to disable GPU emulation. But this means there will be no GPU emulation and the guest system has to use its old GLES version. This will be a slow android emulator.

Solution: 
./emulator -gpu off

Comment: thanks for your effort. the problem was actually caused by the absence an "Intel HD Graphics" Driver on my windows 10 (Dell Inpiron 15). it worked fine the moment i installed it.

Answer (score 0):

worked solution for me is just update display driver
or
uninstall driver and resart